# Script attribute not set to javascript function value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am trying to set the attribute of the script tag for a infomous word cloud as follows:

```
<head>
  function getParameterByName(name)
  {
  ...
  }
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" 
async data-infomous-id="javascript:getParameterByName('wcid');" 
id="embed" 
src="http://www.infomous.com/client2/?width=800&height=600&maxWords=40">
</script>
</body>
```

But the javascript function is never executed. How can I set the **data-infomous-id** dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do this trick:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/egLnM/1/)

```
var elem = document.getElementById('embed');
elem.setAttribute('data-infomous-id', getParameterByName('wcid'));
```

Comment: Added your code into  $(document).ready(function () {...}); and it worked. Thanks!